# Two for-loops in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list-comprehension

For a project I want to get the words out of the document path that leads to afile and return them in a list. I can accomplish this by using a list comprehension, regex and a for-loop:

```
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        themen = [x for x in re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+',path)]
        themen_final = []
        for i in range(4,len(themen)):
            themen_final.append(themen[i])
        print(themen_final)
```

This works fine, but I am sure, that one can put the for-loop `for i in range...` also in the list comprehension above. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `print([re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+',path)[4:] for path, subdir, files in os.walk(directory)])`

Comment: Or, `print([item for sublist in [re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+',path)[4:] for path, subdir, files in os.walk(directory)] for item in sublist])`

Comment: I'd go with the most readable and easy to read one. It doesn't matter how much lines you take :)

Comment: @belthazorNv I totally agree with you. I was just curious about the possibility of putting two for-loops in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that with a list comprehension, the `for` loops take the same order as you would normally write them. So

```
for a in range(4):
    for b in a:
        pass
```

would become

```
[pass for a in range(4) for b in a]
```

With this knowledge it becomes pretty easy to rewrite any loop to a comprehension. You take the end to the front and then put the `for` behind it. Because you make a small list with `themen_final = []` we start with:

```
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        themen_final = [themen for themen in re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+',path)[:4]]
```

and doing the same trick once more to arrive at:

```
[[themen for themen in re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', path)[:4]] for file in files for path, _, files in os.walk(directory)]
```

Though I would even expect that you are either interested in `re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', path + file)` or that you could do without the `for file in files`. Now you would always get the same result for each file. :)